# nat2::[(Integer,Integer)] definition

Tags: list, haskell, syntax

> ### Define a list:
>
> ```
> nat2::[(Integer, Integer)]
> ```
>
> that contains all pairs of nonnegative
>   integers ordered by the relation known
>   from the proof of Cantor theorem:
>
> ```
> (x1,y1) < (x2,y2) <=> x1+y1 < x2+y2 v (x1+y1=x2+y2 ^ x1 < x2)
> ```
>
> [^- means alternative]
>
> such that:
>
> ```
> nat2 = [(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(0,2),(1,1),(2,0),(0,3),(1,2),(2,1),(3,0),...]
> ```
>
> #### Hint:
>
> definition should fit in one
>   line and be shorter than 45
>   characters. Notice that the sum of
>   coordinates of points laying on on the
>   same diagonal is constant.

I made some definition, but am not sure if it is correct, could you check/repair/give tips:

```
nat2::[(Integer,Integer)]
nat2=[(a,b-a)|b<-[0...],a<-[0...b]]
```

EDIT: CHANGED TO:

```
nat2 :: [(Integer,Integer)] 
nat2 = [(a,b-a) | b <- [0..], a <- [0..b]]
```

with result:

```
Prelude> :load "nat2.hs"
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( nat2.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> take 10 nat2
[(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(0,2),(1,1),(2,0),(0,3),(1,2),(2,1),(3,0)]
```

Comment: The code does not even compile so it is not correct. Please try running your code in ghci before asking us if it is correct.

Comment: now it is working, updated in question

Comment: Why all these downvotes? The OP showed a question, posted what he did and asked for help. I see no reason for voting down. And BTW, you can format something as code by indenting it with four whitespaces. You can even nest quotes and code. (I didn't know this before ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a syntax error (did you try running it and checking the output?)

```
Prelude> [(a,b-a)|b<-[0...],a<-[0...b]]

<interactive>:1:14:
    A section must be enclosed in parentheses thus: (0 ...)
```

Because you only need two `..` in the list enums:

```
Prelude> take 10 [(a,b-a)|b<-[0..],a<-[0..b]]
[(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(0,2),(1,1),(2,0),(0,3),(1,2),(2,1),(3,0)]
```

Looks reasonable, but you are the best to judge.

Comment: nat2 :: [(Integer,Integer)] 

nat2 = [(x,s-x) | s <- [0..], x <- [0..s]]

that one works, called with : take 10 nat2

Comment: yes i made syntax error while writing it here..sorry.
good ver. updated after edit in question.